# Index 2 requested with size of 2

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, indexing, size

I am newbie to android development and here is my first project of gridview database.
it show error "index 2 requested with size of 2"

I am using sqlite database db file

here is my code

Please help me!!!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
GridView data;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            li);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(getString(R.string._sdcard_sales_db), MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users", null);
        if (cr != null) {
            if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String desc = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("user"));
                    li.add(desc);
                } while (cr.moveToNext());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("user")),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        cr.close();
        mydb.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR" + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: error shown on which line ?

Comment: No sir it occured when running module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do {
    String desc = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("user"));
    li.add(desc);
} while (cr.moveToNext());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("user")),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

After the do-while loop, the cursor `cr` points to a row after the last valid row.

Remove the `Toast` where you call `getString()` with an invalid cursor index, or change it to toast the information you actually want.